# showing a non-Euclidean property in Geometry

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

To show that in a Hyperbolic space:  given a line and a point exterior this line , there are ifinity many lines that pass through this point but do not intersect the given/initial line. 
Where the Hyperbolic space is defined as:
$H= {z : Im(z) > 0}$,  it includes all the lines that are parallel to imaginary axis( or vertical to the real axis)  and all the half balls that there centers are on the real axis.

Comment: Please provide some context. What is the ambient space, or what are the axioms? E.g. the statement holds for $\Bbb R^3$, though you probably want to do plane geometry.

Comment: @Berci thanks for notifying، my space is the Hyperbolic space

Comment: I guess, hyperbolic plane. Is it defined by axioms or construction?

Comment: Are you aware of "Upper half space" or "Unit disk" models ? Does these terms speak to you ?

Comment: unit disk model: hyperbolic points are interior points of unit circle in the Euclidean plane. "lircle" means "line or circle." hyperbolic lines are intersection of lircles orthogonal to unit circle with interior of unit circle.

Comment: @Jean Marie i guess did not hear this before , but i may be allowedto use it in this question because it doesn't specify...

Comment: What is the definition that has been given to you of "hyperbolic space" ?

Comment: By the way, intuitively, we are given two lines $f,g$ through $P$ which doesn't intersect line $e$, then no line through $P$ in the angle enclosed by $f,g$ intersects $e$.

Comment: @Jean Marie i added the definition of Hyperbolic space

Comment: @Berci i edited the post

Comment: Ok, great. Can you solve the special case when the given line is a vertical line?

Comment: @Berci i did not succeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first we are given a point $p=a+bi$ and a vertical line $e$ with points $u+xi$ with a fixed $u\in\Bbb R, \ u\ne a$ and a varying $x>0$.

Without loss of generality, assume $u>a$, and pick any $s\in (a,u)$ in the real line (which is the boundary of the upper plane model). Then the line from $p$ orthogonal to $\overline{s\, p}$ intersects the real axis at a point $t>u$, and $p$ is on the circle with center $\frac{s+t}2$ and radius $\frac{t-s}2$, by Thales' theorem. 
The whole circle is strictly to the right of $e$ (its leftmost point is $s$), so doesn't intersect it, and the interval $(a,u)$ contains (continuum) infinite many points, each giving rise to a different 'line' (orthogonally intersecting semicircle).

Finally, we can either do a similar construction for the case $e$ is a semicircle, or we can use some transformation to conclude the general case.

Comment: Thanks @Berci I'm trying to accomplish it in a drawing but don't see how the line from p can be orthogonal to sp?

Comment: That's the place where I introduced it, you can't find it in the picture, just draw a perpendicular to line of $s$ and $p$ from $p$.

Comment: can you explain the other case, it may help me to understand it better :)

Comment: You should definitely draw it. You have a point $s$ on the real axis, $p$ somewhere on the plane, to the right of $s$, connect them and put a perpendicular to it from $p$: it will intersect the real axis to the right of $p$.

Comment: Can it be solved with equations?